# Create custom block inside header

Tags: layout, blocks, template

i want create a custom block inside the header wrapper.
I have put the code inside the default.xml from my child theme and have created a .phtml file with a h1 for test, but it's not working.

The .phtml file is in: /Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/header-links.phtml

My Code in the default.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <container name="header-links-test" htmlClass="container_css_class" htmlTag="div" after="top.search">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::templates/html/header/header-links.phtml" name="block_name" />
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your code by removing "templates" word from your template path.

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <container name="header-links-test" htmlClass="container_css_class" htmlTag="div" after="top.search">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/header-links.phtml" name="block_name" />
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: please vote my answer and mark it resolved.